# "Data structure" for a fermion field

Tags: computational-physics, fermions, software, lattice-model, grassmann-numbers

I am understanding the path integral formalism of fermion fields. Most textbooks told me that grassmannian integration is only algebaric notation. It shouldn't be understood in a *Lebesgue Integral* manner. A fermion field ψ at some point is just a grassmannian generator. One cannot *assign* it with any value.

However, It seems that the grassmannian algebaric is connected with exterior algebra. i.e., A grassmannian algebra with 100 generators can be *represented* in a $2^{100}$ dimensional linear space. Textbooks in lattice simulation told me that computer cannot handle grassmannian variables. But I guess the only reason is $2^{100}$ is too large.

So my question is:
for the path integral formalism of a bosonic field on a $10\times10$ lattice, we can imagine something like:

```
float boson[10][10];
float Action(float boson[10][10]);
float two_point_function(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){
    float numerator=0, denominator=0;
    for(i=1;i<99999;++i){
       generate_random_configuration(boson);
       weight=exp(-Action(boson));
       numerator+=weight*boson[x1][y1]*boson[x2][y2];
       denominator+=weight;
    }
    return numerator/denominator;
}
```

And get the correct answer with an unrealistically powerful computer. Then

**What is the "data structure" for a $10\times10$ fermion lattice field? I guess it should be a float array of $2^{100}$ elements.** But how is it organized? How the action is related to that giant float array?

Edit:

I'm trying to go a little further. Firstly, let's talk about lattices in k-space. So we can concisely say "one lattice site=one quantum site". Now the question becomes the fock space for a boson/fermion system of 100 energy levels.

Thinking...

Comment: If you have a hundred spin-1/2s the dimension of the Hilbert space is also $2^{100}$.

Comment: The reason is much more basic: standard computer languages like C or FORTRAN do not know what a grassmann algebra is, and how to manipulated these objects, while they do know how to handle complex numbers (ie "bosons"). The size of the Hilbert space has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: @Adam. I am regret to disagree with you. We can teach computers how to deal with complex numbers, even quaternions. For example, the Julia language has its builtin complex number support.

Comment: Of course we can. But this hardly make for a nice numerical method to treat fermions. Anyway, my main point is that the problem is not the size of the Hilbert space (i.e., tu number of lattice points).

Comment: The Grassmann algebra is just the exterior algebra (see [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExteriorAlgebra.html), [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exterior+algebra), [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/Supernumber), and [good old WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number)).  The superstitions about Grassmanns ultimately stem from confusing the elements of an exterior algebra with the generators of that algebra.